# Cakephp:How can i filter list results not to duplicate

Tags: cakephp

Hie guys,please i want to know how i can filter my results from a list so that they don't duplicate the same results.I don't want items with the same name to repeat.My list is as follows.

```
$list[]=$this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->
find('list',array('fields'=> array('programme_code','programme_name'),
'conditions'=>array('subject_code'=>$s_code,'compulsory'=>'true')));
```

Its finding,but repeating the     programme_code and     programme_name.I dont want duplicates,please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add group by with query. Try this

```
$list[]=$this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->
find('list',array('fields'=> array('programme_code','programme_name'),
'conditions'=>array('subject_code'=>$s_code,'compulsory'=>'true')
'group' =>array('programme_code')));
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLs DISTINCT is what you want. http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2007/07/25/select-distinct-with-cakephp/

Add "DISTINCT ProgrammeRequirementsSubject.subject_code" to the fields list of your query options.